# Using Python to combine csv files with headers on different rows

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to combine a bunch of csv files. Each csv file has a different number of columns. This is not a problem, I can easily loop through the files and pull in all the column headers, pasting them into an empty file to use as a base.

The problem I'm having is that the column headers are on different rows in each file.

For example:

```
Table1
Random Text
!,Header1,Header2,Header3
*,123,124,5235
*,124,15,23624
*,135,677,234

Table2
Random Text
Random Text
!,Header1,Header2,Header4
*,124,2156,7478
*,126,12357,547
*,237,12,267

Output:
Table,Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4
Table1,123,124,5235
Table1,124,15,23624
Table1,135,677,234
Table2,124,2156,7478
Table2,126,12357,547
Table2,237,12,267
```

My existing code looks something like this:

```
files = glob.glob(r'//Directory/*.csv')


#This block goes through each file and works out which variables exist
variablelist=[]
for f in files:
    with open(f,'r') as csvfile:    
        read_rows = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in read_rows:
            if row[0]!="*":      #The last row with no * in column 1 is the header row
               rowlist = row    
        variablelist.extend(x for x in rowlist if x not in variablelist)
        list.sort(variablelist)
```

I use the fact that the header row is the last row without a * in the first column. I work out which row the headers are on and then store the header names in a list - combining the same list from all files.

I then try and combine the files together using this code that I found by searching this website:

```
with open("out.csv", "w", newline="") as f_out:   # Comment 2 below
     writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=variablelist)
     for f in files:
         with open(f, "r", newline="",) as f_in:
             reader = csv.DictReader(f_in)  # Uses the field names in this file
             for line in reader:
                 # Comment 3 below
                 writer.writerow(line)
```

The problem is, I don't know how to deal with the headers being on different lines. I tried using code to define the header row number, but don't know how to implement this into the code above - (Can dictreader skip a dynamic number of rows before finding headers?)

```
with open(f,'r') as csvfile:
                 read_rows = csv.reader(csvfile)
                 header_row_number = 0
                 for row in read_rows:
                     if row[0]!="*": 
                         header_row_number=read_rows.line_num
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Is there anything you can say definitively will be true of the header row and now true of the "random text" lines?

Comment: @Actuary Do the header rows have an '!' at the beginning or is that just a note?

Comment: @Daniel Gale Nathan Hinchey The header rows always have an ! At the beginning, but it's possible for the row to be duplicated (eg two header rows on consecutive lines with an ! At the beginning). I guess one option is to assume header is the first one with a !, and then ignore the other lines with ! later on?

Comment: @Actuary I was thinking to create a dictionary list of all possible header columns and then read the data and output the rows if the column exist for that row